# EmberJS - How to refresh Application template after updating a property from a child controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an `ApplicationController` and a `LoginController`. When the `LoginController.login()`action is called the `ApplicationController.login()` is triggered as well. The "Login"-template is updated, whereby the "Application" template remains as initially set by still displaying "Not logged in, yet". How to update/trigger the Application template so that "Logged in!" is shown?

Templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <p>
        {{#if isLogin}}
            Logged in!
        {{else}}
            Not logged in, yet
        {{/if}}
    </p>
    <p>{{outlet}}</p>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login">
    <h1>LoginController</h1>
        <p>
        {{#if isLogin}}
            Logged in! <button {{action 'logout'}} class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
        {{else}}
            Not logged in, yet <button {{action 'login'}} class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        {{/if}}
        </p>

 </script>
```

Here the javascript code

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isLogin : false,
    actions: {
        login: function() {
            this.set('isLogin', true);
        }
    }
});
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["Application"],
    isLogin : false,
    actions: {
        login: function() {
            this.set('isLogin', true);

            this.get('controllers.Application').send('login');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://jsbin.com/rayor/1/) is a DRY'er working jsbin

**Original Response**

[here](http://jsbin.com/rutay/1/) is a working jsbin

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isLogin : false,
    actions: {
        login: function() {
            this.set('isLogin', true);
        },
        logout: function() {
            this.set('isLogin', false);
        }
    }
});

App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["application"],
    isLogin : false,
    actions: {
        login: function() {
            this.set('isLogin', true);
            this.get('controllers.application').send('login');
        },
        logout: function() {
            this.set('isLogin', false);
            this.get('controllers.application').send('logout');
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Couldn't you use something like the following in App.LoginController to DRY up the code? {{action 'auth' 'login'}} with actions: { auth: function(method) { this.toggleProperty('isLogin'); this.get('controllers.application').send(method); }}

Comment: Duncan is right this code code be simplified - I did not do so to emulate the original code.  E.g. there is no reason to have two isLogin attributes.  It could reside in the ApplicationController and LoginController can either set it there or as Duncan suggests have an action handler that sets it.